# Programmatically get Carrier time in android

Tags: java, android

I am relying on device time in  my application ,where we have a time policy for user such that he can  only use mobile application during specified time period. When mobile is connected to network the time on device will be accurate but in offline we can not trust device time i.e. It has to work without network where I can't rely on user time.

I felt it's a challenging to learn but I have a little time to implement, any suggestion's would be great unless removing the offile policy :)

Thanks and regards,
karthik kondlada

Comment: can you add more details to your question?

Comment: I have an application where we allow user to use the application for certain duration, hence we get the time limit from server and check for application expiry time. Now we are planning the application to be used in offline support, so I have limited with online support to check application expiry. I thought as every mobile phone has a carrier, hence can we not use the carrier information to get updated time so that My job is done.